# Assembly control flow after calling printf

Tags: assembly, x86-64, control-flow

I'm working on an assignment where I have write equivalent assembly code to a given C program that finds prime factors of numbers.
While debugging with gdb, I noticed some strange behaviour in the order that statements are executed. After the first call of `printf`, it hops back to `divq %r8` in L1, and I don't really understand why. There is no jump statement and the division results in a floating point exception which crashes my program. Any ideas what's going on? Don't mind the obvious logical error for now :)

This is my source code:

```
    .file "factor.s"
    .section    .rodata
    strout: .string "%ld %s\n"
    STR0: .string "is a prime factor"

    .text
    .globl factor
    .section .text

factor:
        pushq   %rbp            # setup stack frame
        movq    %rsp, %rbp      # setup stack frame
        movq    %rdi, %r8       # save first param(n) in r8
        shrq    $1, %r8      # bitshift r8 by 1 (div by 2)
                                # int64_t f = n/2 complete
                                # f is in r8
        movq    %rdi, %rax      # save first param in rax
        movq    %rdi, %r9       # save first param in r9
L0:
        cmpq    $1, %r8         # while (f > 1)
        jbe     L1              # if f is not greater than 1
        cqto                    # convert %rax to %rdx:%rax

        idivq   %r8             # It hops back here somewhy
        cmpq    $0, %rdx        
        je      L1              # break (jump if %rax equals 0)
        decq    %r8             # f--
        jmp     L0              # if f still is greater than one
                                # jump to L0

    L1:                         # outside while loop
        cmpq    $1, %r8         # compare f and 1
        je      L2              # if f == 1, jump
        movq    %r9, %rax
        cqto                    # convert %rax to %rdx:%rax
        divq    %r8             # n%f
        movq    %rdx, %rdi      # push param
        call    factor          # factor (n/f)
        movq    %r8, %rdi       # push param
        call    factor          # factor(f)
        jmp     L3              # skip else block

    L2:
        movq    %r8, %rsi       # push params, fixed pushing rax to r8
        movq    $strout, %rdi   # push params
        movq    $STR0, %rdx     # push params
        call printf             # printf
    L3:
        leave                   # cleanup stackframe
        ret                     # and return


        .globl  main
    main:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        movq    $11, %rdi   # 11 for easier testing
        call    factor
        movq    $0, %rax
        ret
```

And this is my debugging log(gdb).
The info registers are:

> ```
>     rax            0x2  2
>     rbx            0x0  0
>     rcx            0x0  0
>     rdx            0x2  2
>     rsi            0x2  2
>     rdi            0x2  2
>     rbp            0x7fffffffdfd0   0x7fffffffdfd0
>     rsp            0x7fffffffdfd0   0x7fffffffdfd0
>     r8             0x1  1
>     r9             0x2  2
>     r10            0x4  4
>     r11            0x1  1
>     r12            0x400400 4195328
>     r13            0x7fffffffe0d0   140737488347344
>     r14            0x0  0
>     r15            0x0  0
>     rip            0x40053f 0x40053f <L2+3>
>     eflags         0x246    [ PF ZF IF ]
>     cs             0x33 51
>     ss             0x2b 43
>     ds             0x0  0
>     es             0x0  0
>     fs             0x0  0
>     gs             0x0  0
>     (gdb) s
>     48  movq    $STR0, %rdx     # push params
>     (gdb) 
>     49  call printf             # printf
>     (gdb) s
>     2 is a prime factor
> ```

The error message is:

> Program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
>   L1 () at factor.s:38
>   38      divq    %r8             # n%f
>   (gdb) s

Program terminated with signal `SIGFPE`, Arithmetic exception.

Comment: Your symptoms suggest incorrect assumptions about printf's calling convention. You might want to compare your code to what your C compiler emits for an equivalent printf statement.

Comment: the output assembly from a hello world program with placeholders in C is similar to mine, except for the use of `puts` instead of `printf` . In earlier test programs I have also used `printf` similarly without any bugs

Comment: 1) use function `int foo(long long n) { printf("%lld", n); return 0; }` to avoid `puts` optimization. 2) earlier program works = may be just accidental, when your assembly program after running produces expected output, that's usually hardly any sign of correctness, there may be still serious problems in it. 3) in 64b check the ABI of your target platform, especially stack alignment requirements.